# Windows embedded 7: Get out of kiosk mode on web site error

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-ce, kiosk-mode

**Introduction:** I have a symbol MC18N0 Barcode Handscanner device which we use to start transport orders for an automated guided vehicle system.

The problem is that I want to hide the installed OS from the operator as much as possible. Therefore I configured the scanner to open the Internet Explorer in kiosk mode and I have set it's start page to our web site where the operator can scan the source and destination codes for the required transports.

Everything works as expected, as long as there do not occure any errors in the network or server side (e.g. web server not available).

Once the internet explorer on the device shows up an error message, I am not able to recover from it, as it's in kiosk mode and i cannot access any menu (the device has no keybord). So I can't reload the page nor can I shut down the IE.

**Question:** Is it possible to redirect all errors to a local web page on the device? By this I can implement a reload and exit button on that error page and can get out of the situation.

Currently I have to unscrew the battery cover and to remove the battery. But this is not a real solution for on site.

Thanks for any Idea.